# Is there a fallback for the now-defunct x-webkit-speech in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, speech-recognition

As I found out just today, [Google Chrome has dropped support for `x-webkit-speech`](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/jlPdpx6jErE) a while back. I've used this rather extensively in my projects, and I'm looking for a sort of "hack" to get this working again.

Is there a method to change something, tweak a setting, add some JavaScript or something to get `x-webkit-speech` working again? I've heard of the new Speech API, but I was looking for other options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the post you referenced indicates on the depreciation of the x-webkit-speech they mention a new Java API. It is hard to find good references to this API and would lead me to believe that is also in a research stage.  Here is a [link to a code lab at SpeechTek](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vH9Zf86XNuqIwUFg5OJn56Q2qP3HeMEUoezx0NPQddY/edit) last year that introduced the API. It also has links to code examples and other documentation.

I would be wary using anything Google has not "officially" released in production code.  I had been burned by this before, as well as many others, for [using the unofficial weather API that Google just suddenly dropped](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2012/08/google-weather-api-is-dead.html).

Comment: this is the most helpful answer (and probably one of the few I'm going to get anyways), thanks.